# Adjusting volume in car switches iPhone to music

Tags: iphone, audio, music, podcasts

Since our phones updated to 12.2 my wife and I have both experienced the following problem in each of our Toyotas - when listening to a podcast (on Stitcher) if we adjust the car audio volume the phone will suddenly switch to playing music. I have also experienced this once in a rental Toyota. I'm curious if others are seeing the same thing in other cars or with other podcast platforms. It is super annoying and of course if anyone has a fix I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Check out Toyota's latest firmware update, see if they address it.

Comment: I have 2 Toyota's and 1 Hyundai, all with CarPlay.  My wife and I have never experienced this.  The only thing similar we've experienced is when we hit the 'mode' button on the steering wheel, instead of the volume, by accident.

Comment: Unfortunately the latest firmware update is from Sept 2017 which predates the latest iPhone update that caused this problem. fsb do you use Stitcher for podcasts or another app?

Comment: You’ve considered using an aux cable, right?